# rxjs/webSocket: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302 (Edge) / WebSocket connection to <ws_endpoint> failed (Chrome)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, rxjs, keycloak

I've added a piece of code in my Angular project to connect to a WebSocket server. My backend is a Reactive Spring Boot application that uses Spring Security. When the WebSocket client tries to connect, it will send 302 in response in order to redirect the user to the Keycloak Login page.

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private webSocketSubject$;

  constructor() {
    this.webSocketSubject$ = webSocket('ws://localhost:9090/secured-websocket');

    this.webSocketSubject$.asObservable()
      .subscribe({
        next: (v) => console.log(v),
        error: (err) => console.log(err),
        complete: () => console.log("Complete")
      });
  }
}
```

When I open the console in the browser (Edge), I can see the following error: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9090/secured-websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302`

Somehow in Chrome, the message isn't the same: `app.component.ts:16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9090/secured-websocket' failed:`

I tried adding a try/ catch block, I used the [rxjs/catchError operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) but both haven't really given any useful or different error details.

The error that gets printed to the console by the line `error: (err) => console.log(err)` looks as follows,

[image]

Could someone please point out what is missing in the above code or what needs to be added in order to get the error code. If the error is a 302, I want to fetch the redirection url, validate it and route the user to the Keycloak Login page. `err.status` and `err.code` are both `undefined`.

Links to repos: [Frontend](https://github.com/sakethsusarla/webflux-keycloak-struggle/tree/merge-oauth2-client-resource-server/frontend) | [Backend](https://github.com/sakethsusarla/webflux-keycloak-struggle/tree/merge-oauth2-client-resource-server/backend)

I have tried connecting to the endpoint without securing it. The communication works fine. I could even see the messages pushed by the WebSocket server in the console

[image]

Comment: how you tried connecting to the endpoint without securing it?
and how you tried connecting to the endpoint with securing it?

Comment: I made changes to the SecurityConfiguration in my backend. I added `permitAll()` to the `pathMatchers("/secured-websocket")`. This permits anyone trying to access this endpoint. Here's a link to the [configuration](https://github.com/sakethsusarla/webflux-keycloak-struggle/blob/merge-oauth2-client-resource-server/backend/oidc-client/src/main/java/com/example/oidc/client/config/SecurityConfiguration.java)